# toggle() not working for content loaded with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, toggle

```
$('.slideArrow').toggle(function (event) {
  //some code
}, function (event) {
    //some code
});
```

This works fine for content which are loaded on page-load.But the same function does not work for content loaded with ajax.It just does not intercept the click.

What should I do?

In an other scenario,i faced a same problem(not for toggle,for click) and sorted it this way.I dont know what to do for toggle?

```
$('.common-parent').on('click','.target-of-click',function(){
//some code
})
```

Comment: toggle() doesn't work for any content, as that version of toggle() is deprecated and removed ?

Comment: its working...ia m using jquery-1.8.0.min.js

http://www.arrowlife.com/index-v3

Comment: delegate click event instead of using toggle() method

Comment: It was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9, so it would work in 1.8.0, but do you think it's a great idea to use a method that you know is deprecated and removed ?

Comment: @TusharGupta:http://www.arrowlife.com/index-v3  click the arrow on right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag method :

```
var flag = false;

$(document).on('click', '.slideArrow', function(event) {
    if (flag) {
        // do one thing
    }else{
        // do another thing
    }
    flag = !flag;
});
```

the data method

```
$(document).on('click', '.slideArrow', function(event) {
    if ( $(this).data('flag') ) {
        // do one thing
    }else{
        // do another thing
    }

    $(this).data('flag', !$(this).data('flag'));
});
```

Comment: the first flag method is not good for more than one .slideArrow element

Comment: @A.Wolff - It's not really good for anything, but it's simple so I thought I would include it. I always use the data method without globals and relative to the passed element etc.