# .toggle() function not work correctly

Tags: jquery

I have this script and when  page load `$(#menu)` selector fade and return value `123`
I want first click return `aa` and second click `123` how fix it ?

```
$("#menu").toggle(function(){
    alert("aa");
},
function(){
    alert(123);
});
```

Comment: That version of `toggle()` has been deprecated and removed from jQuery

Comment: `toggle()` no longer works in this way: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: how I can fix my problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032913/toggle-not-working-for-content-loaded-with-ajax

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/1359/
check dis fiddle  i created for toggle()

Comment: @user3218194 Thanks man, please tell me how I can toggle function  with special property like, width or margin :)