# Toggle Function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have added

```
$( "#target" ).toggle(function() {
    alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
    console.log("HIiiiiiiiiiii");
}, function() {
 alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
 console.log("Helooooo");
});
```

In Html i  have added.

```
<div class="calendarcell"><a href="" id="target" >'+ val.Title + '</a></div>
```

Can u please suggest Me

Comment: [.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

Comment: Js file is the <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: so what i have to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032913/toggle-not-working-for-content-loaded-with-ajax

Comment: Yeah Adeno for this js what i am using,that code is not working what u  have given link

Answer (score 0):

as toggle for function is deprecated. You can use something like this:

```
 $( "#target" ).click(function() {
    var isclicked= $(this).data('isclicked');
     if(isclicked){
         funct1();
     }else{
         funct2();
     }
     $(this).data("isclicked", !isclicked);
 });
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zdnv957v/)**

Comment: i had checked with some alert box

Comment: @Abhishek: see the demo above

Comment: ,what i have to replace with ('isclicked')

Comment: Here U ahve use jquery 1.11.0, but m using jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js.if i use my calendar picker is not showing ,Like Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' is showing

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the data attribute for checking the event,

```
$('#target').live('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).data('flag') ) {
        console.log("HIiiiiiiiiiii");
    }else{
        console.log("Helooooo");   
    }

    $(this).data('flag', !$(this).data('flag'));
});
```

Comment: Yeah Vaibhav Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'  is showing